# Define UltiSnip With Variable Default Placeholder

Tags: javascript, vim, ultisnips

I'm using the excellent [UltiSnips Vim plugin](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips) to help improve my development workflow. I've been using it for several years now, and it has really helped me automate a lot of my redundant typing while coding.

Anyhow: I'm attempting to define a snippet that helps me generate Javascript require statements.

A normal Javascript require statement looks something like this:

```
let express = require('express');
```

So, here's the snippet I defined:

```
snippet req "require a module" b
let ${1} = require('${2}');
endsnippet
```

This lets me type `req` in Vim, which will then move my cursor to the `${1}` position in the snippet so I can define the variable name. Once I hit  a second time, my cursor will be moved to the location of `${2}` in the snippet, this way I can define the actual Javascript module name to import.

This works fine, but what I'd like to do is take it one step further. I'd like to make a snippet such that:

When I enter a value for `${1}`, the value `${2}` is updated to be the value of `${1}` by default. This way, I can save on typing the same module name twice in certain situations.

The idea is that I should be able to do something like this:

```
snippet req "require a module" b
let ${1} = require('${2:${1}}');
endsnippet
```

This way, if I type:

```
req<tab>express
```

I should end up with the following expanded line:

```
let express = require('express');
```

However, it should also work in this situation:

```
req<tab>exp<tab>express
```

Which would output:

```
let exp = require('express');
```

Does that make sense?

Anyhow: any help would be appreciated! The code sample above does not work like I thought it would. The `${2:${1}}` bit is ignored and doesn't work as expected (*it doesn't set the placeholder value of `${2}` to `${1}`*).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following snippet satisfy both `req<tab>express` and `req<tab>exp<tab>express`: (a slight modification of your idea)

```
snippet req "require a module" b
let ${1} = require('${0:$1}');
endsnippet
```

`$1` is mirror for placeholder `${1}`. Also replaced `2` with `0` as snippet ends in this placeholder.
To add **visual** support just add `${VISUAL}` to placeholders. As @**lwassink** provided instructions, i just give snippet:

```
snippet req "require a module" b
let ${1:${VISUAL}} = require('${0:$1}');
endsnippet
```

Comment: Thank you. The first option is perfect: succinct, tiny, no Python interpolation required <3

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with python interpolation.

```
snippet req "require a module"
let ${1:${VISUAL: my_name}} = require ('`!p snip.rv = t[1]`');
endsnippet
```

Once you add it to your javascript snippets file, it should work exactly as you have described.
Type `req<tab>express` and you'll get

```
let express = require ('express');
```

As a bonus, the snippet also works in visual mode.
To use it this way, type `express`, then select express in visual mode.
You can do this by positioning the cursor on the word you want to select and typing `viw`.
Then, with the module name selected, enter `<tab>req<tab>` to run the snippet.
This is useful if you remember you want to use a require statement after typing the name you want to require.

I learned most of this from Drew Neil's Vimcasts.
He has a series of three on Ultisnips, starting with this one: http://vimcasts.org/episodes/meet-ultisnips/.